# Why do you curl the wire when making electromagnets?

Tags: current

What is the scientific explanation for adding turns in the wire when making an electromagnet? If two wires had the same length - would the one with several turns be a stronger magnet than the straight wire with no turns?

Comment: Yes because it concentrates the field

Comment: Well you have to put the arms around and hug tight to get the full warmth ;-)

Comment: The magneto-motive force (MMF), \$\small F_m\$, which is the parallel of EMF in electrical circuits, is \$\small F_m=NI\$ (current x turns). This is often given the unit At (for ampere turns), but since 'turns' is not an SI unit, the strict unit is amp (A)

Comment: @JonRB Oh, I meant: "Yes, but HOW does it concentrate the field? It would be neat if you could elaborate a little to clarify :)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know from Biot Savart law that a current carring wire will generate a magnetic field surrounding the wire.

\$ B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}\$

or more generically: \$\oint B\space dl = \mu_0I_{enc} \$

[image]

Now if the wire is looped it can be seen that the direction of the magnetic flux starts to concentrate in the centre of the loop.

[image]

With more loops the flux is further concentrated 
[image]